# I have exactly same code in DEV and PROD and few properties(PII data) on PROD is masked and on DEV its not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, masking, pii

I'm seeing SSN masked on PROD and it is not masked on DEV with same exact code. I looked up the stored procedures it is calling and it is simple select statement. I inquired DB admin and he said they are not doing any masking, since they are using SQL server 2012 he is pretty sure it is not happening on sql server side(sql server 2016 and up year can do masking on DB).

I need suggestions what else I can debug or is it possible to do masking on SQL server 2012?

Comment: My PROD is using SQL server 2012 and it is masking. In my scenario I don't want masking I'm debugging to remove masking. So I tried to reproduce issue locally and PII data is not masking. Initially I thought masking might be happening on SQL server and asked DBA to check on PROD server and according to him he did not see any masking on PROD SQL server.(PROD and DEV are using 2012)

Comment: I don't know how dynamic masking works (or doesn't work) with linked servers. Is that a possibility?

Comment: It turns out to be network team is intercepting calls and masking PII data before sending it back to client.